# Why am I getting "no such account" error with a destination charge, stripe connect, after correctly doing the onboarding process?

Tags: node.js, express, stripe-payments

I am building a website that utilizes [Express Stripe Connect accounts](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/express-accounts) and I have set up the onboarding process already. As a user I can create an account, successfully go through the Oauth flow, and then get back

```
2019-07-17T07:39:21.184623+00:00 app[web.1]: { access_token: 'sk_live_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
2019-07-17T07:39:21.184639+00:00 app[web.1]: livemode: true,
2019-07-17T07:39:21.184641+00:00 app[web.1]: token_type: 'bearer',
2019-07-17T07:39:21.184644+00:00 app[web.1]: stripe_publishable_key: 'pk_live_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
2019-07-17T07:39:21.184647+00:00 app[web.1]: stripe_user_id: 'acct_XXXXXXXXXXXX',
2019-07-17T07:39:21.184649+00:00 app[web.1]: scope: 'express' }
```

I replaced the real numbers with "X"s, but you can see that the Oauth flow is finishing successfully, and then I store the stripe user ID in my firebase.

Then another user attempts to make a destination charge, and tokenizes their credit card with a built in stripe element, from stripe, and then makes a call to my backend to create the charge.

```
const charge = stripe.charges.create({
      amount: req.body.amount,
      currency: "USD",
      source: req.body.source,
      application_fee_amount: app_fee,
      transfer_data: {
          destination: stripe_vendorID,
      },
    }, postStripeCharge(res));
```

```
const postStripeCharge = res => (stripeErr, stripeRes) => {
  console.log(stripeErr)
  console.log(stripeRes)
  if (stripeErr) {
    res.status(500).send({ error: stripeErr });
  } else {
    res.status(200).send({ success: stripeRes });
  }
}
```

But for some reason, every single time that I try and pay the the stripe user ID that I just got from the oauth flow I get this error:

```
{ Error: No such account: acct_XXXXXXXXXXX
    at Constructor._Error 
    at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1064:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
  type: 'StripeInvalidRequestError',
  rawType: 'invalid_request_error',
  code: 'resource_missing',
  param: 'destination',
  message: 'No such account: acct_XXXXXXXXXXXXX',
  detail: undefined,

etc. etc.
```

The ID matches the one in firebase, as I just pulled it from there, but for some reason it keeps saying the account doesn't exist. I've been at this forever now, trying to figure out where I'm going wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you _sure_ the API key you're using in `stripe.charges.create` is the same one you used when you called https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/token ? (i.e it's definitely the same platform that connected the account and is making the charge request?)

Comment: Yes.The ID that is being used to create the charge as well as create the user account is the same.

Comment: What is the weirdest part is on the stripe dashboard it says "6 accounts connected" on the chart, from my earlier attempts, but then it says "0 connected accounts" on the Connect tab..

Comment: A common problem I've seen is that if you make an OAuth request using the same access token, it actually disconnects the account(since the OAuth spec says that reusing an access token should revoke access to protect against replay attacks). Maybe that's it? You connect the account, but you accidentally make another call to the /oauth/token endpoint reusing the `ac_xxx` and it disconnects the account.

Comment: That was the issue!

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this problem was exactly what karllkekko said: I was accidentally making multiple requests each time I was doing the oauth flow, and so it was connecting and then disconnecting the accounts. I created a boolean in my state, combined with a callback function to ensure it only sent requests once, and now it works like a charm!